# Java Rainbow Tables- compute method

Tags: java, hash, rainbowtable

I am trying to write a program using Rainbow Tables to hash and hack passwords of length four. The algorithm for the hash value is: ℎℎ = (163 ∗ ℎ   0) + (162 ∗ ℎ   1 + (161 ∗ ℎ   2) + (160 ∗ ℎ   3).

I need help figuring out what I did wrong on the compute method. There are comments before the code saying what needs to be done if that will help solve the problem.

```
public void compute() {
    //TODO:  Add code to compute all possible 4-letter passwords - store in rainbow
    // Begin your possible passwords with aaaa and end with zzzz
    // Use hashCode(pwd) % 29 to determine the key (index) of where this element should be added to rainbow's ArrayList of ArrayLists
    // You will need to cast as int, such as key = (int) hashCode(pwd)%29  - key is the index of where to add this element in the rainbow ArrayList of ArrayLists
    if(password.length() != passwordLength){
        throw new InvalidPasswordException();
    }
    while(password.startsWith("aaaa") && password.endsWith("zzzz")){
        key = (int) (hashCode(password)%29);
        rainbow.add(key, password);
    }
}
```

please let me know if anymore information is needed.

EDIT: here is the entire code so all the other methods can be seen (Not all are complete yet)

```
import java.util.*;
public class HashMap implements HashMapADT{
private String password;
private Long hash;
private int key;
private final int passwordLength = 4;
ArrayList<ArrayList<PasswordMap>> rainbow;

public HashMap() {
    password = "";
    hash = -1L;
    key = -1;
    initializeHashMap();
}
public HashMap(String str) {
    password = str;
    hash = hashCode(str);
    key = (int)(hash % 29);
    initializeHashMap();
}

private void initializeHashMap() {
    //Initialize an ArrayList of 29 elements - when dividing by 29 only remainders 0 - 28 are possible
    rainbow = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
        rainbow.add(new ArrayList<PasswordMap>());
    }
    compute();      
}

public Long hashCode(String str) throws InvalidPasswordException{
    this.hash = 0L;

    //TODO:  Calculate hashCode using hashing function based on powers of 29

    return 0L;  // temp - delete once hashCode method is implemented.
}

public void compute() {
    //TODO:  Add code to compute all possible 4-letter passwords - store in rainbow
    // Begin your possible passwords with aaaa and end with zzzz
    // Use hashCode(pwd) % 29 to determine the key (index) of where this element should be added to rainbow's ArrayList of ArrayLists
    // You will need to cast as int, such as key = (int) hashCode(pwd)%29  - key is the index of where to add this element in the rainbow ArrayList of ArrayLists
    if(password.length() != passwordLength){
        throw new InvalidPasswordException();
    }
    while(password.startsWith("aaaa") && password.endsWith("zzzz")){
        key = (int) (hashCode(password)%29);
        rainbow.add(key, password);
    }
}
public Long hash(String pwd) {
    //TODO:  Return the hashcode for a given password
    // First, hash the password: int key = (int)(hashCode(pwd) % 29);
    // Use this key to determine which element in the rainbow table you should be traversing to find the hash code
    // Recall rainbow is an ArrayList of ArrayLists!!
    key = (int)(hashCode(pwd)%29);

    return 0L;  // temp - delete once hash method is implemented.
}

public String hack(Long pwdHash) {
    String pwd="";
    //TODO:  Given a hashed password, pwdHash, determine the password
    // When identifying a correct hashed password, you will need to look at a difference RATHER THAN ==
    // That is, 
    //if (Math.abs(pwdHash - rainbow.get(key).get(i).getHash())<.001)  -  you've found your password!!
    // Note:  key is the location of the rainbow list you should be traversing:  key = (int)((pwdHash) % 29);


    return pwd;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return password + ": " + hash;
}
```

}

Comment: "figuring out what I did wrong" would make more sense if you told us what behaviour you expected to see, and what behaviour you actually saw.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your `while` loop.

`while(f())` means "keep doing this as long as `f()` returns true".

You've said "keep doing this as long as `password` starts with "aaaa" and `password` ends with "zzzz".

We don't see you initialise `password` but if it's a four char string as described, it's impossible for it to both start with "aaaa" and end with "zzzz", so the while loop's block will never execute.

If `password` was `"aaaazzzz"` so that the condition was true, then, since you never modify the value of `password`, the while loop would repeat forever.

You probably want something like:

```
for(int i=0;; i++) {
    String password = createPassword(i);
    rainbow.add(password, hash(password));
}
```

... and write a method `createPassword()` such that `createPassword(0)` returns "aaaa", `createPassword(1)` returns "aaab", `createPassword(26)` returns "aaba" and so on.

Comment: I edited the original question and added the rest of the class code in case that changes your answer.